# Cloud function not working in local emulator

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am learning about cloud functions, the function **HelloWorld** works in the emulator but the **updateUserRoleCron** is not working, when I use "run npm serve" in the console this happens, thank you in advance. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOlWa.png)

Function:

```
 exports.updateUserRoleCron = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 24 hours').onRun(async (context) => {
  const thresholdTimestamp = Date.now() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // Hace 30 días
  const usersRef = admin.firestore().collection('users');

  try {
    const snapshot = await usersRef.where('role', '==', 'subscriber').where('lastUpdate', '<=', thresholdTimestamp).get();

    const batch = admin.firestore().batch();

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      batch.update(doc.ref, { role: 'normal' });
    });

    await batch.commit();

    console.log('Roles de usuarios actualizados correctamente');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al actualizar los roles de usuario:', error);
  }
});
```

ran npm serve to load cloud functions in local but an error shows up

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.